# Passing variable from index to controller using Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I am new to using Laravel and I am currently trying to pass a variable from the index blade file to the controller in order to bring up all apparatus type fields associated with a specific apparatus code id.

I am able to access the apparatus type fields associated with the apparatus code id when I include a specific number which correlates to that apparatus code id (eg. inputting 2 brings up the apparatus type details for the apparatus code id 2, inputting 3 brings up the apparatus type details for the apparatus code id 3 etc).

However when I have tried to pass a variable relating to each individual apparatus code id using a for loop in the controller, the apparatus type loop appears to not be accessed and does not return any information. I will include snippets of my current code for clarity.

Any help or guidance with this issue would be greatly appreciated!

**Controller file**

```
public function index()
    {
        $apparatusCodes = ApparatusCodes::get();
       foreach ($apparatusCodes as $apparatusCode){
     $apparatusTypes = ApparatusTypes::where('apparatus_code_id', $apparatusCode->id)->get();
 }
        return view('apparatus_codes.index', compact('apparatusCodes', 'apparatusTypes'));
    }
```

**Index.blade file**

```
<table id="datatable" class="stripe hover dt-responsive display nowrap" style="width:100%; padding-top: 1em;  padding-bottom: 1em;">
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th>ID</th>
          <th >Apparatus Code</th>
          <th>Description</th>
          <th>Rent</th>
          <th></th>
        </tr> 
      </thead>
<!--start of for loop-->
@foreach ($apparatusCodes as $apparatusCode)
    
      <tbody>
         <tr data-toggle="collapse" id="table{{ $apparatusCode->id}}" data-target=".table{{ $apparatusCode->id}}"> 
          <td> {{ $apparatusCode->id}} </td>
          <td>{{ $apparatusCode->apparatus_code}} </td>  
          <td> {{ $apparatusCode->description}}</td>
          <td> {{ $apparatusCode->rent}}</td>
          <td @click="isOpen = !isOpen" class="main-bg"><img class="mb-1 duration-300  h-6 w-6" :class="{'transform rotate-180' : isOpen}"
                    src="../img/Icon-arrow-dropdown-white.png" alt="arrow down">
          </td>
          <td><img class="mb-1 duration-300  h-6 w-6" :class="{'transform rotate-180' : isOpen}"
                    src="../img/edit-icon.svg" alt="Edit Icon">
          </td>
        </tr> 
        <tr x-show.transition.duration.300ms.origin.bottom="isOpen" x-cloak @click.away="isOpen = false" class="collapse table{{ $apparatusCode->id}}">
          <td colspan="999">
            <div>
              <table id="datatable" class="table table-striped">
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                  <th>Apparatus Code </th>
                  <th>Apparatus Type</th>
                  <th>Compensation </th>
                  <th>Created On </th>
                  <th>Created By </th>
                  <th></th>
            
               
    @foreach ($apparatusTypes as $apparatusType)
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                
    <tr>
     
            <td>{{ $apparatusCode->apparatus_code}}</td>
            <td>{{ $apparatusType->apparatus_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $apparatusType->compensation }}</td>
            <td>{{ $apparatusType->created_at }}</td>
            <td>{{ $apparatusType->users->name}}</td>
            <td> <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-edit js-edit"><img class="mb-1 duration-300 ml-4 inset-0 h-6 w-6" src="/../../img/Icon-edit-gray.png" alt="edit"></button></td>

                                       
        </tr>
        @endforeach  
      </table>
    </tr> 
</tr>
</td>
      </tbody>
    
    @endforeach
  </table>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ... you are overwriting `$apparatusTypes` each iteration of the `foreach` loop ... are you trying to get ApparatusTypes for every ApparatusCode? (a relationship would help here) ... in your view there is no direct relationship between an ApparatusType and an ApparatusCode

Comment: Thank you, yes each ApparatusCode has an ApparatusType - I had tried to set up relationships between ApparatusType and ApparatusCode in the models eg. in the ApparatusType model I've included public function apparatusCodes()  
{  

 return $this->belongsTo(ApparatusCodes::class, 'id' );  

}                                                                                                                                            and in the ApparatusCode model I've included public function apparatusTypes()  
{  
  return $this->hasMany(ApparatusTypes::class, 'apparatus_code_id');  
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the relationships setup you could eager load the `ApparatusTypes` for each `ApparatusCode`:

```
$apparatusCodes = ApparatusCodes::with('appartusTypes')->get();
```

Then in the view you could iterate the `appartusTypes` of each `ApparatusCode`:

```
@foreach ($apparatusCodes as $apparatusCode)
    ...
    @foreach ($apparatusCode->apparatusTypes as $type)
        ...
    @endforeach
    ...
@endforeach
```

Without using the relationships you could get all the ApparatusTypes for the ApparatusCodes and then group them by `apparatus_code_id`:

```
$codes = ApparatusCodes::get();
$types = ApparatusTypes::whereIn('apparatus_code_id', $codes->pluck('id'))
    ->get()
    ->groupBy('apparatus_code_id');
```

Then in the view you could iterate the group that corresponds to the current Code's `apparatus_code_id`:

```
@foreach ($codes as $code)
    ...
    @foreach ($types->get($code->id, []) as $type)
        ...
    @endforeach
    ...
@endforeach
```

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Eloquent - Relationships - Eeager Loading](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships#eager-loading) `with`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-pluck) - `pluck`

[Laravel 8.x Docs - Collections - Available Methods](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/collections#method-groupby) - `groupBy`

Comment: I have implemented your first solution involving eager loading and that appears to have worked thank you for all the help! I'll read the documentation on eager loading to fully understand it going forward, thanks again!

Comment: no problem, i will add some documentation links for things used in the answer ... if the answer is what you were looking for feel free to accept the answer